# Mocking interface clone method

Tags: java, mockito

Mocking a `clone()` method on an interface appears to no longer be working with **Mockito 2.1.0**. The below code works fine with **Mockito 1.10.19** but throws an `IllegalAccessError` with **Mockito 2.1.0**:

```
public interface CloneableInterface extends Cloneable {
   CloneableInterface clone();
}

public class CloneableInterfaceTest {

   @Test
   public void test() {      
     CloneableInterface i = Mockito.mock(CloneableInterface.class);
     Mockito.when(i.clone()).thenReturn(i); // Throws IllegalAccessError
   }
}
```

Result of running above test:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: CloneableInterface$MockitoMock$833899610.clone()LCloneableInterface;
```

I checked the mockito bug list and googled a bit but found nothing. Wanted to check SO community first before filing a bug report with the mockito team.

Environment: **JDK 1.8.0_102**, **JUnit 4.11**, **Mockito 2.1.0**, **Gradle 3.0**, **Windows 10**

**EDIT:** Filed a bug with the mockito team [here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/688)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Mockito.

Since `Object::clone` is `protected` and since Java favors subclass inheritance over interface inheritance, the automatically generated subclass overrides `clone` as a `protected` method, rather than a `public` method. Of course, Mockito should render all overridden methods as `public` but currently Mockito is not doing this. This is however trivial to fix. Expect this to be resolved in a future release.

Comment: Wow, a fix in ~35 min after reporting this bug on githum. Very impressed.